# How do I export links from my bookmarks to Dropbox

Tags: samsung, dropbox, bookmarks

I have collected many bookmarks on my Samsung Galaxy S3. Many of these I wish to use on my desktop computer. How do I export all the links from all the bookmarks on my phone and put them where Dropbox will upload them to my desktop computer?

Comment: Even though I could not see the links from the mobile phone on the desktop, once I

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Also, where are the bookmarks/links you're trying to export -- are they on the home screen? in a browser?